# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while using site_url() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use `site_url()` in codeinginter form action attribute:

```
 <form id="register_form" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/signin" method="POST" role="form" style="display: none;"></form>
```

I am getting above attribute in ajax request:

```
    url: $("#register_form").attr('action'),
```

Now, while submitting the form, I am getting an error like:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/index.php/signin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://islamicquiz.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have defined `islamicquiz.com` as virtual host on my local server.
Before using site_url(), and using hardcoded url instead, everything was working fine.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Cross Origin Resource Sharing dictates that the site you are making the request from is allowed access through the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers. There are several posts on the right -------> under *Related** that ask this same question, and it's always the same problem.

Comment: i went through all answers. I am on the same site, on my local machine. The answers are given in the context that someone is using different hosts.

Comment: I can see it says `islamicquiz.com` in your code.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, that is a virtual host on local server. The issue remains the same with out the above modification.

Comment: What does your virtual host or local server or anything have to do with how CORS responses work? `Origin 'http://islamicquiz.com' is therefore not allowed access.` Show me your code where it has nothing to do with that DOMAIN and it's all Local and I'll believe you.

Comment: ok, give me a minute.

Comment: Use base url or form_open http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart also if your using Ci3 you must set your base url in config.php

Comment: i am getting the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/index.php/signin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.` after disabling the virtual host.

Comment: Well of course, you don't want to disable the virtual host. My point is that the `site_url()` is returning you a `Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)` which is why it's trying to resolve there. You can either set the origin headers, or you can change the URL so that it's a local host only project. This is the code that I was talking about.

Comment: So, what are the workaround? will the above code work in case of production servers? Also, as other answers suggests that setting header for the same is not secure at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script in php file...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
```